Windows NPS 802.1X Rejecting Certificate due to Enterprise Root CA not Trusted by NPS Server
For first off the problem: As noted I have an NPS Server that is rejecting connection attempt due to:
"The certificate that the user or client computer provided to NPS as proof of identity chains to an enterprise root certification authority that is not trusted by the NPS server".
The problem is, as best I can tell, the root CA is in fact trusted by the NPS server.
Here is my configuration:

My root CA is a Windows standalone root CA (not domain joined, usually kept offline).  The certificate for this root CA has been published in the domain.
My NPS server does in fact have the above mentioned root CA certificate in the Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates store
I have a domain joined Enterprise Intermediate CA.  As it is domain joined, the certificate for this CA is published to the  Local Computer\Intermediate Certification Authorities\Certificates store
Certificates for 802.1x clients are issued by this enterprise issuing CA
Windows Server 2022 across the board
In this particular case, the NPS server is also my Domain Controller
for this test my client device is a Ubuntu 22.04 machine.  I have tried configuring it with a certificate containing only the end certificate as well as which a full chain certificate.  Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Based on the above, everything I can see show that there is in fact a chain of trust to a trusted root CA.
While researching this I came across this link for certificate requirements:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/certificate-requirements-eap-tls-peap
The above configuration seems to match all of these.  I even added the offline root CA cert to the NTAuth store in the domain just in case - no change.
Can anyone point me in a direction?  Googling this error message doesn't return much.

What CA issued a client certificate to your Ubuntu box? The error says that NPS doesn't trust client certificate, not own cert.

@Crypt32  - this issuing CA mentioned in point 3 above is the one that issued the cert to the Ubuntu client.  This is the part that confused me - the cert is issued by my CAs which all have their certs stored in the relevant trusted cert stores of the NPS machines.
